# Keep Filter from HttpPost on next page of PaginatedList in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am creating a program in which I have a Database with records I want to filter.
The filter has 4 input type="text" and returns the right records based on the filters I typed.
The problem is, when I click Next Page link (of PaginatedList), the second page has no filters adapted.
It lose the filters I gave. I know I must give asp-route on Next Page link some variable with the data given in filter like Microsoft Tutorial gives currentFilter, but I have 4 filters like this :
Name=x&Phone=y&...

Here is my Controller Code simplyfied :

```
 public  async Task<IActionResult> Index( some variables ){ 

   var appusers = from a in _context.AppUsers
                           select a;

   return(return View(await app.PaginatedList<AppUser>.CreateAsync(appusers.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));)
}


AND

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string Name, string Phone, string Calls, string Date){
       
              var ap = from c in _context.AppUsers
                     select c;
              Filter The database based on variable values Name,Phone,Calls,Date

              return View(await PushNotificationApp.PaginatedList<AppUser>.CreateAsync(ap.AsNoTracking(), 
               pageNumber?? 1, pageSize));}
```

Here is the part of Index :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AppUsers", new { id = "filterForm" }))
        {
 name="SearchTrips" value="@ViewData["CurrentTrips"]" />

                <input id="NameFilterField" type="text" name="Name" />
                <input id="PhoneFilterField" type="text" name="Phone" />
                <input id="CallsFilterField" type="text" name="Calls" />
                <input id="DateFilterField" type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" name="Date" />
           

            <button class="m-3" type="submit" value="submit">Search</button>

        }

AND PAGELIST LINK PART :
 <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link MainButton" asp-action="Index"
                                       asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
                                       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"       
                                       class="page-link @prevDisabled">
                                        Previous
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link MainButton" asp-action="Index"
                                       asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
                                       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"                         
                                        Next
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, when I click Next Page link (of PaginatedList), the second page has no filters adapted. It lose the filters I gave.

You are doing the filter in the `Post` action, but when you click the Next link, it will go to the `Get` action which not filter. So, I think you can make the form do a get request and just do the filter in the Get method.

> I know I must give asp-route on Next Page link some variable with the data given in filter like Microsoft Tutorial gives currentFilter, but I have 4 filters like this : Name=x&Phone=y&...

4 filters is the same, just give the other filter parameters to the `Next` link

```
<a class="page-link MainButton" asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
   asp-route-Name="@ViewData["Name"]"
   asp-route-Phone="@ViewData["Phone"]"
   asp-route-Calls="@ViewData["Calls"]"
   asp-route-Date="@ViewData["Date"]"
   Next
</a>
```

Comment: Hi @George Dim,if it can work for you, could you please accept it as answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

why not use a single box to search everything or four search boxes using the method below in the tutorial?

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                           || s.FirstMidName.Contains(searchString));
}
```